# Using Apache proxy rules to make internal services available externally

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I've searched for about an hour now, and although there are many relevant examples, none have helped me solve this issue.

I have several local servers, lets call them print server and managed switch. Both of these devices host administration pages on port 80. I also have an apache2 based webserver.

What I want to do is visit `example.com/printserver` and have it manage a proxy connection to the print server.

Many examples will show you something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPass /printserver http://[local IP of print server]/printserver
    ProxyPassReverse /printserver http://[local IP of print server]/printserver

    ProxyPass /switch http://[local IP of managed switch]/switch 
    ProxyPassReverse /switch http://[local IP of managed switch]/switch 

</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't make logical sense to me. The administration pages of these devices are not at `/printserver`, they are at `/`.

When I configure apache with the following, I am able to achieve what I want for one service

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPass / http://[local IP of print server]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://[local IP of print server]

</VirtualHost>
```

Furthermore, I notice that when I configure apache with the following, it attempts to proxy to my service, but because the service returns a relative URL, the `printserver` portion is merged with the relative address and the whole thing falls down.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPass /printserver http://[local IP of print server]/printserver
    ProxyPassReverse /printserver http://[local IP of managed switch]/switch

</VirtualHost>
```

E.g, in the previous example where it worked, my browser displays
http://example.com/pathtoindex/indexOfPrintServer.php

in the second example where it falls down, my browser shows
http://example.com/printserverpathtoindex/indexOfPrintServer.php

If I use the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPass /printserver/ http://[local IP of print server]/printserver
    ProxyPassReverse /printserver/ http://[local IP of managed switch]/switch

</VirtualHost>
```

Then my browser shows the following, which fails because `http://example.com/pathtoindex` won't get picked up by my Proxy rules and isn't handled by any other virtualserver.

http:\example.com\pathtoindex\indexOfPrintServer.php

What I would like to achieve:

When I visit `http://example.com/printserver`, I want to see what I see when I visit `http://[local IP of print server]` on my local network.

Likewise, when I visit `http://example.com/switch` I want to see what I see when I visit `http://[local IP of managed switch]` on my local network.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `proxyhtmlurlmap` which intercepts the page in transit and updates the HTML url tags to accomodate the extra path element.

However in my particular setup this was ineffective as both server pages had some nasty javascript in that ganerated some URLs on the client side. It's obviously next to impossible to inspect the HTML in transit and fix these issues.

I used iptables in the end and settled for accessing the servers by a port. (I couldn't just set this on the router as my router has a very limited number of port forwards).

If I really wanted, I could have apache redirect the example.com/server1 to example.com:xxxx, but it's unnecessary.